Proof that for all nonzero real numbers $a$, $\frac{1}{a}$ is nonzero
I was wondering if someone could check my proof that "For all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, if $a\neq 0$ then $\frac{1}{a}\neq 0$". The definitions/assumptions I am basing the proof off of come from "Intro to Real Analysis" by Bartle and Sherbert Fourth Edition. I have provided an image of what I am using in my proof:
2.1.1 Algebraic Properties of R
I am using (M3), (M4), and Theorem 2.1.2(c). Here is my proof:
Proof. Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Assume $a\neq 0$. Suppose for a contradiction $\dfrac{1}{a}=0$. Then by (M4), $1=a\cdot\dfrac{1}{a}=a\cdot0$. By Theorem 2.1.2(c), $a\cdot0=0$. Thus $1=0$. But by (M3), $1\neq0$, so we have a contradiction. Thus $\dfrac{1}{a}\neq 0$. QED
Is it awkward that I assume $\frac{1}{a}$ to be zero? I ask because if $\frac{1}{a}=0$, it seems that this implies $a=\frac{1}{0}$, which is undefined, so I cannot apply (M4) the way I did in my proof. However I am not sure if this reasoning is correct or my proof is fine as it is.
Any feedback would help. Thanks.

Your proof is fine, and your concern is unfounded because it amounts to another (very similar) proof of your result. That’s because with $a\neq 0$, you can multiply both sides of any equation by $a$ and equality still holds. So from an assumption that $1/a=0$ it would follow that that $1=0$.

If $\frac 1a=0$ then after multiplying by a^2, we find that $a=0$

This simple fact can be extended and used to find the roots of some function of the form $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. We only have to find out the roots of $f(x)$ and eliminate those who are also roots of $g(x)$. In particular , in the case of rational functions , this is very useful.

The reason is that for real numbers $a,b$ and $b\ne 0$ , we have $\frac{a}{b}=0\implies a=0$ by simply multiplying the equation with $b$. By division by $b$ , we get also the opposite direction and finally have $\frac{a}{b}=0\iff a=0$
